# How do I explicitly specify language of email I want to send?

Tags: email, internationalization, django-i18n, djoser

I have a custom user model that have a `preferred_language` field. I want all the emails (activation and password reset) to be sent translated to the language that user specified in profile.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
        (1, "English"),
        (2, "Русский")
    )

    preferred_language = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default=2,
                                                          verbose_name=_("Preferred language"))
```

I thought about setting custom email class but didn't saw in navive djoser's classes any points where I could explicitly set the language of outcome emails despite of ready-to-be-translated style of email templates:

```
class ActivationEmail(BaseEmailMessage):
    template_name = 'email/activation.html'

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(ActivationEmail, self).get_context_data()

        user = context.get('user')
        context['uid'] = utils.encode_uid(user.pk)
        context['token'] = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
        context['url'] = settings.ACTIVATION_URL.format(**context)
        return context
```

Reset password view (which's refference is `settings.EMAIL.activation` used in ActivationEmail class above):

```
class ResetPassword(ActionViewMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    ...

    def send_password_reset_email(self, user):
        context = {'user': user}
        to = [get_user_email(user)]
        settings.EMAIL.password_reset(self.request, context).send(to)

    def send_activation_email(self, user):
        context = {'user': user}
        to = [get_user_email(user)]
        settings.EMAIL.activation(self.request, context).send(to)
```

Comment: When the email will be sent to the user? After clicking a button or automatically after an interaction with the website (e.g transaction, newsletter, signup etc?).

Comment: After signup and clicking “password reset buttob”. I use djoser endpoints.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have never used `djoser`. Would you mind to show the file (probably `views.py`) which actually sends the email or `djoser` does this automatically and you want to set the language before email is sent?

Comment: Yes, I've provided it into the bottom of the question

Comment: I presume that your email template (either `.txt` or `.html`) contains strings that are marked for translation (i.e they contain `{% trans "text" %}` etc), right?

Comment: Yes, but I want to specify in python code which language these `trans` blocks must be translated to.

Comment: OK, we are getting there! Do you store, in some place (session or somewhere else) the preferred language of the user? If so, can you access  this preference inside these two methods (`send_password_reset_email` and `send_activation_email`)?

Comment: Yes, I can! I store preferred language in the user's model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would use the [`override`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.override) context manager that stores the current language on enter (in order to sent the email) and restores it on exit.

```
from django.utils import translation


def send_password_reset_email(self, user):
    context = {'user': user}
    to = [get_user_email(user)]
    lang_code = user.lang_code  # retrieve user's language code here
    with translation.override(lang_code):
        settings.EMAIL.password_reset(self.request, context).send(to)

def send_activation_email(self, user):
    context = {'user': user}
    to = [get_user_email(user)]
    lang_code = user.lang_code  # retrieve user's language code here
    with translation.override(lang_code):
        settings.EMAIL.activation(self.request, context).send(to)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will try it this week and give you a bounty if all will be ok!

Comment: It's not about the bounty. It's about get it to work!!! Waiting for the good news!

Comment: I’m going to come back from the holidays in a week and implement it.

Comment: Oh! OK! Happy holidays Vassily. Sorry, I didn't know. Have fun!

Comment: Glad I was able to help! In fact, I had the same problem with my emails too, and I was implementing it with a far more complicated way until I hit on this handy context manager and a lot of boilerplate code has gone now!