# Djoser change email language

Tags: django, djoser

Is there a way to change the email that is sent in djoser based on the language of the user instance? I have found this question [How do I explicitly specify language of email I want to send?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146547/how-do-i-explicitly-specify-language-of-email-i-want-to-send), but it does not seem to be an option in the last version of djoser, since there are no longer views for each action (activation, reset password etc.) or I have not figured out how it works. Also, I have tried inhereting the UserViewSet class and apply the translation, but I do not know if this is the way to do it and how to specify all the urls of djoser.

```
class UserViewSet(djoser_view.UserViewSet):
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = serializer.save()
        signals.user_registered.send(
            sender=self.__class__, user=user, request=self.request
        )

        context = {"user": user}
        to = [get_user_email(user)]
        language = user.language or 'en-us'
        with translation.override(language):
            if settings.SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL:
                settings.EMAIL.activation(self.request, context).send(to)
            elif settings.SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL:
                settings.EMAIL.confirmation(self.request, context).send(to)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        super().perform_update(serializer)
        user = serializer.instance
        language = user.language or 'en-us'
        with translation.override(language):
            if settings.SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL:
                context = {"user": user}
                to = [get_user_email(user)]
                settings.EMAIL.activation(self.request, context).send(to)


    @action(["post"], detail=False)
    def activation(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.user
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()

        signals.user_activated.send(
            sender=self.__class__, user=user, request=self.request
        )

        language = user.language or 'en-us'
        with translation.override(language):
            if settings.SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL:
                context = {"user": user}
                to = [get_user_email(user)]
                settings.EMAIL.confirmation(self.request, context).send(to)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or has done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can!

You correctly identified the action where mail is send.

```
    @action(["post"], detail=False)
    def activation(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.user
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()

        signals.user_activated.send(
            sender=self.__class__, user=user, request=self.request
        )

        if settings.SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL:
            context = {"user": user}
            to = [get_user_email(user)]
            settings.EMAIL.confirmation(self.request, context).send(to)
```

So after subclassing `UserViewSet` you can provide a template name in `activation` action.

```
        if settings.SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL:
            context = {"user": user}
            to = [get_user_email(user)]
            kwargs = {"request": self.request, "context": context}
            if user.country == "Country1":
                kwargs["template_name"] = "email/country1/activation.html"
            settings.EMAIL.confirmation(**kwargs)).send(to)
```

Djoser is using [`templated-mail`](https://github.com/sunscrapers/django-templated-mail/blob/master/templated_mail/mail.py) to create mail content.

But, as you can see, `user` entity is passed in the context. So I'd rather advise to tweak your settings a bit and do it in the class that's responsible for generating this email.

in your `app/email.py`

```
class CountryActivationMail(ActivationEmail):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if self.context.user.country == "Country1":
            self.template_name = "email/country1/activation.html"
```

and set `CountryActivationMail` in djoser settings as explained [in the docs.](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#email)